# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable nginx

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, dns, cloudflare

how to fix this issues: when i use [www.dbahack.com](http://www.dbahack.com) it show me this message "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable nginx"
[image]

here is my DNS from cloudflare:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

and this is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

what i'm looking for is when i come to write "www.dbahack.com" should redirect to "dbahack.com" and return the content of course,
actually i tried deferent way but always the same issues pls i need ur help
thank you all.

Comment: What is your `www` CNAME pointing to? If I lookup the DNS for your domain, I appear to get a quite different response... there is no `www` CNAME record and there appears to be two `A` records for the www that point to two different IPs, one of which is different to the domain apex? `RewriteOptions inherit` - What are you _inheriting_?

Comment: ... and where/how does Nginx fit into your server config? (If indeed this is your server?!)

Comment: Thank u sir, this is the content of www CNAME {aamcxw334f4u01stely24gh302.alpha.supersonic.ai} actually i just change this content with {dbahack.com} nd it work now, the inherit on .htaccess file i have no clue cause i fond it there by default, and yes now it works www.dbahack.com ==> dbahack.com

Comment: it wasn't working cause i was using an old CDN delivred by supersonic that's why, thank u sir u remind me and save me time have a good day,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by a unique misconfiguration that is unlikely to match the situation of anybody else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The `www` CNAME record would appear to be pointing to the wrong place. This should presumably be set to `example.com` (your domain), but is set to somewhere else entirely (as confirmed in comments).